# I'm doing automation in selenium of freesound.org but there is a problem when I click on login button it is going back to home page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing automation in selenium of freesound.org but there is a problem when I click on login button it is going back to home page.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import getpass

username = input("Enter your user name")
password = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter your password: ")
os.environ['PATH'] += r"C:/webdriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://freesound.org/search/?q=&f=created:[NOW-7DAY%20TO%20NOW]&s=num_downloads+desc&g=0")
time.sleep(1)
login = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log In").click()
email = driver.find_element_by_id("id_username")
email.send_keys(username)
passsword = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password")
passsword.send_keys(password)
login_click = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"]').submit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try click option instead of submit ?

```
login_click = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type="submit"]').click()
```

also login button found as 2nd element, so we need to pass [2].

```
loginbtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[@type='submit'])[2]")
```